# Opening fragment with custom animations and then quickly pressing back causing app to freeze

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing a strange issue.
When I launch a fragment with `setCustomAnimation()` using the following code :

```
/**
     * launch a fragment
     *
     * @param containerID      - frameLayout ID
     * @param fragment         -  fragment we want to launch
     * @param isAddToBackStack - add to back stack???
     */
    public void launchFragment(int containerID, Fragment fragment, boolean isAddToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_transition_enter_fade_in
                , R.anim.anim_transition_exit_fade_out
                , R.anim.anim_transaction_fade_in_pop
                , R.anim.anim_transaction_fadeout_pop)
                .replace(containerID, fragment);

        if (isAddToBackStack) {
            mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

When I quickly press the back button before the animation completes the app freezes.
I have recorded the App screen. Please check the video below :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxFmkFbsB3NhNkRLbm8yQ195TUU/view?usp=drivesdk
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is experiencing state loss before the animation ends.

Replace your:

```
mFragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

with:

```
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

If by changing the code above causes you `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` error,

then you might want to check this [Blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) about what's happening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help but that doesn't solve the problem. Changing to mFragmentTransaction.commit(); doesn't help

Comment: I tried by removing the animation part. Seems like the animation is creating problem because without animation it works properly. Is there any solution??